# Check if the database is true

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my database, there are users (teachers or children), and I want to insert them in sections, for example, section kg1 (A), kg1 (B). I consider (kg1) is the section name, and (A or B) is the type.
In the table (sectionname) there are only 2 rows (kg1 and kg2) and will not add any row else.
SectionID in table (section) is generated automatically.

Is this database true?? Such that I don't want any thing duplicate.

[image]

Comment: it seems ok. looks clear. you should decide dimension of relations, tables can be master, detail, sub detail. you can re-check the structure after set kind of tables'.

Comment: When i insert TeacherSSN and SectionNameID to the section table, they inserted regardless of whether they entered before, so they duplicate.

Comment: SectionID, TeacherSSN and SectionNameID are foreign key in the section table. And because the SectionID generated automatically, they duplicate but the sectionID change

Comment: The problem with such "Help me make my data model" questions is that they're typically too broad for SO, unless it is a specific question about a specific design decision. They would require detailed knowledge about what should be modeled in the real world where even a small scope typically raises a lot of questions during the design process. And SO is designed as a Q & A platform and not for such interactive processes.